# Adding generic event listener with specific callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, aurelia, jquery-events

In an Aurelia viewmodel component, I have the following JQuery code that works to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while a modal is visible and call the save function:

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) { // Ctrl + ___
    if ((event.which == 83) || (event.which == 115) || (event.which == 10) || (event.which == 13)) {  // Ctrl+Enter or Ctrl+S
      // Save button
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($(self.edit_calendar).is(':visible')) {
        self.saveCalendar();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

However, I foresee adding a similar function to 40+ viewmodels, and that doesn't seem very DRY and adds some ugly code to each of my viewmodels.  I would like to create a generic addEventListener function in a singleton class to easily call from each of my views.  Here's what I have in mind:

```
addListenerSave(visible, callback) {
  // Add an event listener to redirect keyboard shortcuts to specific actions
  console.log("addListenerSave()");
  $(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) { // Ctrl + ___
      if ((event.which == 83) || (event.which == 115) || (event.which == 10) || (event.which == 13)) {  // Ctrl+Enter or Ctrl+S
        // Save button
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(visible).is(':visible')) {
          console.log("Keyboard shortcut: Save");
          callback();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then, in my individual components, I should only need the following code on instantiation (in the `attached()` component life cycle):

```
this.config.addListenerSave(this.edit_calendar, this.saveCalendar);
```

However, this does not work.  `saveCalendar()` is called but maybe from another scope/context, so I get an error inside `saveCalendar` that says:

> "Cannot read property 'selectedId' of undefined".

This is referring to the `saveCalendar()` code `if (this.selectedId)...`.  What am I doing wrong?

Finally, should I also be removing this event listener when my Aurelia component is detached?  How?

One alternate idea I had was to use Aurelia's `eventAggregator` to create a global event listener that always is listening for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then publishing a message that can be subscribed in each component.

Comment: As the event handler is bound to the window, wouldn't you just need one event handler, or do you have 40+ windows as well ?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to have just one event listener BUT I need the callback to be different based on which component is currently visible.  So, I basically need a DIFFERENT event listener function at different times.  So my problem still exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully implemented the alternate solution of adding a global event listener that uses Aurelia's EventAggregator to share Ctrl+S/Ctrl+Enter.  Original question still stands but perhaps it wasn't the best approach anyway.  Here's my solution:

**config.js** (global singleton class)

```
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class Config {
  constructor(eventAggregator) {
    var self = this;
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    // listen for Ctrl+S or Ctrl+Enter and publish event
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) { // Ctrl + ___
        if ((event.keyCode == 83) || (event.keyCode == 115) || (event.keyCode == 10) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {  // Ctrl+Enter or Ctrl+S
          // Save button
          console.log("Publishing ewKeyboardShortcutSave...");
          event.preventDefault();
          self.eventAggregator.publish('ewKeyboardShortcutSave', true);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then, inside my component viewmodel **calendar.js**:

```
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class Calendar {
  constructor(eventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
  }
  attached() {
    var self = this;
    // Ctrl+Enter is save
    this.eventAggregator.subscribe('ewKeyboardShortcutSave', response => {
      console.log("I heard ewKeyboardShortcutSave: " + response);
      if ($(self.edit_calendar).is(':visible')) {
        self.saveCalendar();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Works like a charm, and now I can freely add more component event listeners and even extend the functionality to add a global listener for Ctrl+F (for find), etc.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, you're on the right track - but due to the semantics of `this` in JavaScript, you'll need to bind your function. (If you're coming from a C# perspective, it may help to think that all functions in JavaScript are essentially extension methods; as such, passing functions can be VERY powerful.) It's easy to miss this because of the new ES6 class syntax.

This should work to mitigate your issue:

```
this.config.addListenerSave(this.edit_calendar, this.saveCalendar.bind(this));
```

That said, your solution using Aurelia's Event Aggregator is a much better fit for your use case and much more scalable. I thought I'd post this answer to address the original issue, which was simply a matter of function scope.